# Get currently logged in user

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to get the current user logged in? I have a database with accountid, username and userpass.

I want to check it after they logged in in user/pass form in vb.net

And display the current logged in user which is from the database not in windows.

Comment: Environment. UserName shows currently user logged in on computer not in records of account in database table(users)

Comment: How are they logging in to the DB? If it is not using the integrated security option, it must be thru your code, no?

Comment: I have user records in database and a login form in vb.net. after they input the  right credentials, another form will show. And then current user will show/print in textbox or label.

Comment: Then you just need to hold onto the user id in a variable or class somewhere.

Comment: Can you give me an example to do that?

Comment: Are you saying that you need an example of assigning a value to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

```
                        Main.user.Text = txt_user.Text
                        If Main.user.Text = "admin" Then
                            Main.reg_admin.Visible = True
                            Main.log_admin.Visible = True
                            Main.change_pass_admin.Visible = True
                        End If
                        Me.Hide()
```